# convert music to image and back

Tags: converters, wav

i am trying to convert a music file (actually mp3) to a image and then back from image to mp3. It may sound crazy but im editing afterwards parts of the image and then convert it back to mp3.

My actual solution is this way:
MP3 --> convert to wav --> convert to base64 --> convert to pixel's per byte / time (10s) .
then the opposite way to go back.

Because this is depending on the length very resource intensive i am looking for a way to get a graphical output much quicker and render it back much quicker... i dont care about which programming language... im more looking for a better (quicker way) to do it that gets the same result. Most MP3's are songs and between 3-6 Minutes long. So the images are getting very big ;=)

How would you approach this? currently my shell script needs 19 seconds for 1 song which is a way to long. Converting it back takes only 12-14 seconds...

Looking for a solution in Linux with ffmpeg and shell scripts.

Comment: If your current solution works, and you want help to refine/improve that approach then this question should probably go on [codereview.se], rather than here.

Comment: i am currently using ffmpeg , im not looking for a optimisation of the code or ffmpeg. Im looking more for a new approach that i didnt think off or maybe did overlook. Target is to have a music file --> image ... make change on the image...---> convert it back to music . How would some one else do it

Comment: In which the question moves from being 'off-topic' because there's neither any code shown in the question (or for belonging on another site) to being 'too broad' since you're not narrowing it down to any language, library, OS...

Comment: @DavidThomas , thanks... much for this comment such a worthy comment *sarcasm off*. I am using currently ffmpeg on linux and shell scripts that do the conversion. Maybe i should delete the question, because only if code is shown a question gets accepted and no one should ever ask for non coding questions. i was asking this question because i think that my brain thinks in a box and im open for other ideas to solve this problem. but like you wish you can block this question or set it as off-topic, whatever you prefer.

Comment: I've voted to close, for the reason I explained. I'd suggest heading to the support pages to see what's on topic here (I think it's in the [faq] area). While your question may not be on topic here, there are other sites in the network that may be a better fit (have a look at the technology sites, in the footer, or browse a list of all the network sites, available at [se]).